# how DOCKER chain in iptables works?

Tags: docker, nginx, iptables

I'm new to docker.

Recently I experienced somewhat strange scenario.
I created ubuntu instance in OCI(Oracle Cloud Infrastructure).
When I started nginx process in this ubuntu instance, access from external network fails.
When I started nginx with docker container, access from external network successes.

After some search, I found that INPUT chain in iptables does not allow tcp 80.
Additionally, docker will update my iptables to ADD rule in PREROUTING chain.
Here is result of command `sudo iptables -nL -t nat`.

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:80

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 to:172.17.0.2:80
```

But as you can see in DOCKER chain, I think, RETURN rule is always applied former than DNAT rule.
This means, DOCKER chain does not do anything!

Can anybody give any explanations on this?
One possible assumption is that RETURN rule is applied last regardless of order of rule. (But I'm not sure this is true or not).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

RETURN rule actually will be applied at first, but it is not mean to ignore other rules. There also have another two variables IN and OUT which describe the rule's input and output.

You can add `-v` to your command to show it.

```
$ iptables -nL -v -t nat

......
Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   12   720 RETURN     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 1691  107K DNAT       tcp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8601 to:172.17.0.2:8601
......
```